# How estimate GAS from a contract call with Web3j

Tags: contract-development, web3j, java

I'm trying to estimate gas cost of a contract call, i need to send a string to a contract, but i need to see if i overtook the GAS limit.

I'm trying like this:

```
    Transaction t = Transaction.createContractTransaction(myAddress, BigInteger.valueOf(100), gasPrice, gasLimit, null, "0123456789");
    EthEstimateGas eg = web3j.ethEstimateGas(t).send();
    System.out.println("EstimateGas: " + eg.getAmountUsed().toByteArray());
```

But i receive the error:

> Erro: org.web3j.exceptions.MessageDecodingException: Value must be in
>   format 0x[1-9]+[0-9]* or 0x0

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to encode the data by using `FunctionEncoder.encode`
2. Before checking the result you need to check for errors. If an error (for example a contract error) is returned the result will be null and you will get the the error you described.

Do something like this:

```
Function function = new Function("nameOfFunction", ...)
Transaction tx = Transaction.createFunctionCallTransaction(..., FunctionEncoder.encode(function));
EthEstimateGas gasEstimate = client.ethEstimateGas(tx).send();
if (gasEstimate.hasError()) {
  logger.info("Contract error: {}", gasEstimate.getError().getMessage());
} else {
  logger.info("Gas estimate: {}", gasEstimate.getAmountUsed()); // will throw in case of error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is sending a message to the contract (which needs to be hex-encoded). In this case, you want the message to say 'execute function with the following params'.

Take a look at `FunctionEncoder.encode` that should give you what you need.

Comment: In this case, i need to put the hex on Transaction creation in my code example?

Comment: Exactly, take the encoded output from the function encoder and pass it into the transaction.

Comment: @AntonyDenyer So this looks really good and my version compiles but the `EthEstimateGas` object has a `getResult()` that yields null and causes an exception in `getAmountUsed()`.   I build my function with `Function("name", Array of inputs, Array of outputs)` then do `String txData = FunctionEncoder.encode()` and pass it as the last arg.  The contract exists at address 0x... because a generated wrapper method can hit it and get results.   I am connecting to the local `geth --dev` node.
Any quick clues...?